# There was no 404 CMS page configured or found

Tags: magento-1.9

There was no 404 CMS page configured or found.

Backend settins are fixed properly but the issue is occur `There was no 404 CMS page configured or found.`

When I enable compilation process the 404 page not visible in magento

Without compilation 404 page working properly

Comment: Please give some more info. What page are you looking for, what is the URL, etc. Also, are you using the storecode in the url? Like `http://domain.com/en/`

Comment: now i am working in local system

Comment: Ok posted several questions, please all of them by updating your question

Comment: When I enable compilation process the 404 page not visible in magento

Without compilation 404 page working properly

Comment: www.yoursite.com/errors in this folder find local.xml.sample rename it to local.xml

Comment: @Arunendra already i renamed the file

Answer (score 3):

To create a 404 page 
Create a CMS Page with Correct `'Store View'`

then go to `System=>Config=>General=>Web`

in Default pages Tab > `CMS No Route Page` select the recently created 404 Page and save

**Note: after this Refresh Cache and Reindex**

[image: see image]

Comment: When I enable compilation process the 404 page not visible in magento

Without compilation 404 page working properly

Comment: This is a bug I am suffering too, i guess this is a unhandled bug in magento  core, and this is the only explanation I found so far http://www.techytalk.info/blank-product-page-magento-compilation/ 
also check this out may come handy to you https://kb.magenting.com/content/22/38/en/magento-shows-blank-empty-page-how-do-i-solve-this.html